# Test blocked with CasperJS

Tags: casperjs

This is my code:

```
casper.then(function() {
    this.click('.btn-attendee');

    this.waitForSelector(
        '#form_signup2',
        function() {
             this.wait(3000, function() {
            //El parametro 'INFO' es para que el echo aparezca en color VERDE
            this.echo('Existe el popup SIGNUP', 'INFO');

            this.capture('signup.jpg', undefined, {
                        format: 'jpg',
                        quality: 75,
                    });
            this.echo('pantallazo signup', 'INFO');

            this.wait(4000, function() {
                this.fill('form#form_signup2', {
                    'first_name':    'Perico',
                    'last_name':    'Palotes',
                    'email':    new Date().getTime()+'@testing.es',
                    'password':    '123456'
                    //Ponemos false porque sino nos haria el SUBMIT del formulario y no queremos eso.
                    //En el email la pasamos un numero aleatorio para que no de fallo al ejecutar el script varias veces
                }, false);

                this.evaluate(function() {
                    document.getElementById('checkbox1').style.display="block";
                })

                this.click('#checkbox1');
                this.wait(1000, function() { this.click('.final_button'); });

                    this.wait(15000, function() {                     
                         this.capture('signup2.jpg', undefined, {
                            format: 'jpg',
                            quality: 75,
                        });

                        this.echo('pantallazo  signup2', 'INFO');
                        this.wait(1000, function() {
                                    this.echo('Existe el popup del paso2 SIGNUP', 'INFO');
                                    this.wait(2000, function() {
                                            //RELLENAMOS EL FORMULARIO DEL 2º POPUP DE SIGNUP EMAIL
                                            //FORMUARIO FASE 1 
                                            this.fill('form#form_step3', {
                                                'user_alias':    new Date().getTime()+'Perico',
                                                'town':    'Valencia',
                                                'role':    'uno',
                                                'company': 'testing_company'
                                                //Ponemos false porque sino nos haria el SUBMIT del formulario y no queremos eso.
                                            }, false);

                                            this.wait(2000, function() {
                                                this.capture('form2.jpg', undefined, {
                                                    format: 'jpg',
                                                    quality: 75,
                                                });

                                                this.echo('pantallazo  form2', 'INFO');
                                                 //MY PROBLEM
                                                 //Here I try to make a this.wait with a this.echo, but if I do get stuck in the test phase ... this.echo('pantallazo  signup2', 'INFO')
                                            });
                                    });      
                        });                            
                    });
            });             
            });
        },
        function(){
            //El parametro 'ERROR' es para que el echo aparezca en color ROJO
            this.echo('error login', 'ERROR')
        },
        10000
    );
});
```

In the last attempt this.wait I have put in with the other this.wait with this.echo for example, but if I do and I run the script I get stuck here:

`this.echo('pantallazo  signup2', 'INFO');`

That I can do to make this wait another where I have mentioned that the test is not blocked?

Comment: What do you mean by "get stuck"? Are you getting an error?

Comment: The test remains in execution, but in a part of the test stands still fails to enter one of the this.wait not get error

Comment: Maybe you should post the output?